# Using random in JSP5

Tags: processing, p5.js

Does someone know how I can fix this problem?

```
var Arguments [2003,1002,3932,10203,2030,1828912,12912]
var Argument = Arguments[Math.floor(Math.random() * Arguments.length)]
```

Because of these variables, a random argument is always chosen at the beginning. However, if you are in the program and switch from page to page, it will keep the random value it had at the beginning. I want him to be constantly creating new values.

In the draw function I call the argument like this:

```
text(Argument, 300,180);
```

Comment: Math.random() doesn't need a seed. Do you re-run the code where you ask for a random number, or just re-use the `Argument` variable?

Comment: I am not familiar enough with P5.js to deduce what you need to do, but as I seem to be the only one to try and debug this, I suggest that you post more code so I can get a better understanding of what you're doing and how to get the result that you want. A [minimal, working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be great!

Comment: What do you mean "switch page to page" ? You need to provide some context because there are different ways to answer your question depending on the rest of your program.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question and the comments correctly, you need re-assign `Argument` to be a different random value each time you switch pages, such as this line every time it switchs:

```
Argument = Arguments[Math.floor(Math.random() * Arguments.length)];
```

You don't put `var` there every time. Give it a value in `setup()`, then re-assign it when you need another value.

Unless, of course, I completely missed your problem.

Comment: I believe in this guy. Unless `switch from page to page` means something else than what I think it means, he's right on the money.

Answer (score 0):

In `p5.js` there is a helpful function called  `random`

so you could use it like this

```
var Arguments [2003,1002,3932,10203,2030,1828912,12912]
var Argument = Arguments[random(0, Arguments.length - 1)]
```

you can read more about it [here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/random)

Answer (score 0):

Make argument into a function.

```
var Arguments [2003,1002,3932,10203,2030,1828912,12912];

var Argument = function(){
    return Arguments[ Math.floor( Math.random() * Arguments.length ) ];
}

text(Argument(), 300,180);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make a random selection in setup() it will only happen once in    your whole script. Also, Don't choose variable names that might already be    used by the system (I suspect "arguments" might be.

```
let args = [2003,1002,3932,10203,2030,1828912,12912];
let a;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  a = random(args);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  textSize(30);
  text(a,50,70);
}

function mousePressed() {
  a = random(args);
}
```